# Find rules that matches the URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a set of URL rules in the form of array.

```
const rules = [
{"page":"url","containsIgnoreCase":["google.com/something.html"]} ,
{"page":"query","equals":["testing=true","tt="]} ,
{"page":"url","containsIgnoreCase":["www.netflix.com/mx/products.html"]} ,
{"page":"url","containsIgnoreCase":["www.google.com/products/premiere.html","www.google.com/products/premiere-rush.html"]} ,
{"page":"url","containsIgnoreCase":["test=testing"]} ,
{"page":"url","containsIgnoreCase":["facebook.com/free-trial-download.html"]} ,


{
"and":[
        {
            "equals":["www.google.com"],
            "page":"domain"
        },
        {
            "equals":["/fr/products.html/","/fr/products.html"],
            "page":"path"
        }
    ]
},
{"and":[{"contains":["https://www.google.com/uk/","https://www.google.com/de/"],"page":"url"},{"page":"path","equalsIgnoreCase":["/uk/","/de/"]}]},

{"or":[
        {
            "and":[
                    {
                        "equals":["www.google.com"],
                        "page":"domain"
                    },
                    {
                        "equals":["/resources/rlmkt.html/","/resources/rlmkt.html"],
                        "page":"path"
                    }
                ]
        },
        {
            "page":"url",
            "containsIgnoreCase":["https://www.netflix.com/resources/rlit.html","https://www.netflix.com/resources/indht.html"]
        }
    ]
} ,
```

];

I need to write a function, that accepts the url and returns all the rules that matches the URL given.

For ex:

input = "https://google.com/something.html"

output = [{"page":"url","containsIgnoreCase":["google.com/something.html"]}]

Answer (score 0):

> For ex:
> input = "https://google.com/something.html"
> output =
> [{"page":"url","containsIgnoreCase":["google.com/something.html"]}]

to get above output, use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#examples)

```js
const url = new URL('https://google.com/something.html')
const containsIgnoreCase = url.hostname + url.pathname
console.log(containsIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: the URL needs to checked against those rules, to identify whether it matches the given conditions. sometime, rules contain domain info, sometimes path, sometimes query params etc. which is also available in that object.